# Fastreport and TSQLQuery

Tags: delphi, dbexpress, fastreport

I use `TSQLQuery` (from DBExpress) to run a query on two Mysql Tables. Now i want to print a report from that Query using `FastReport` but i don't know how to do it!

Help me please.

Answer (score 2):

If you enable the query at runtime (fill in relevant params if need be in the designer), you can doubleclick the TSQLQuery to bring up the field designer.
Choose `add all fields`.

Now you can add a datasource to that `TSQLQuery` and link the fields to your FastReport.

Comment: Thank you, but when i choose `add all fields` i get this error : `Missing query, table name or procedure name.`

Comment: My Query will execute in Run-Mode and i can't access fields in Design-Mode.

Comment: Is the query connected to a SQLConnection in design mode or only at run-time?

Comment: @Kermia, well there you have it, connect the stuff at design time, and then you can see the fields of the query. If you connect at runtime, you'll have to link the fields to the report at run-time as well.

Comment: There is a lot of data from different tables that i need. So, can i link the fields from different tables to report at design-mode?

Comment: Yes. You can link your components up to a grid and see whether you are getting the correct values before committing yourself to FastReport.

Comment: I have a big problem and my information are coded in tables. In fact, I have to decode them before making a report :|

Comment: @Kermia, you use a select with joins for that, if you're stuck feel free to ask a specific question 'bout that.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise you to connect the query to the default SQLConnection at design time, and not at run-time, as you are currently doing (according to your comment). This will enable you to see the fields of the query and so link the correct fields to the FastReport.

Comment: So, there is now way to make a report at run-time?

Comment: I have a big problem and my information are coded in tables. In fact, I have to decode them before making a report :|

Comment: Maybe that should be another question, "how do I write the sql query which will give me the following result?" If you choose to do so, list the structure of your tables.